# Python - ошибка list index out of range при заполнении двумерного массива

Tags: python, массивы

Имеется следующий код на Python:

```
import random
index = 0
Z = list(range(1,9))
random.shuffle(Z)

a = []
for i in range(3): 
    a.append([]) 
    for j in range(3):
        a[i].append(Z[index])
        index += 1
```

При запуске программы выдает ошибку list index out of range. Я в питоне только начинающий, помогите разобратся. В упор не вижу, что не так в программе.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Спсиок `Z` содержит 8 элементов, с индексами от `0` до `7` включительно.

Во вложенном цикле значение переменной `index` достигает `8` - как следствие, "вываливание" за границу списка...

Comment: Спасибо, я оказывается просто забыл, как работает range